# RT-AC87U guest network security

Tags: wireless-networking, router

Question on configuring guest network on an Asus RT-AC87U.

Background:  I have two legacy IP cameras that will only work using WEP (or no) security.
I don’t want to use WEP on either my 2.4GHz or 5GHz networks because of security issues.

I setup a guest network without any security and the cameras work fine with port forwarding and static ip’s.  But I really don’t want to allow open internet access on my network.

Question:  Any ideas on how to configure the router so that I can still use my legacy cameras but restrict my network from unwanted users?  Is there a way to only allow specific MAC (or IP) addresses on the guest network only?

Suggestions (other than to tell me to get new cameras)?

Answer (score 0):

Assume you've checked to see if theres a FW update for the cams?

NB: Dont have an ASUS router to dig through the UI, so going on whats "normal". What you're looking at is MAC Filtering or MAC Restriction. You can probably turn this on, its quite a common feature, but I wouldnt be surprised if that works on all VLANS(Regular and guest) which is a pain in the face to maintain (every device needs to be whitelisted, only the truly tinfoil hat use it).

What could be a better solution is if you have your old router or could get your hands on an old one. If yes, set that up as AP(DHCP OFF, Static IP) and configure it as an a cam only AP. Give it an SSID, Turn SSID beacons off("hiddden network"), security to OPEN and MAC filtering on. Then connect the cameras to it. Will also mean the cameras wont hog bandwidth on the main WLAN APs.

Answer (score 0):

MAC or IP whitelisting in the guest network would not add any real security. It will prevent someone from accidentally connecting to your network, but is as leaky as a keypad door with the keycode written in large letter on the door.

> Suggestions (other than to tell me to get new cameras)?

You could place wireless access point next the the camera and put both that AP and the camara's antenna in a cay of Faraday. That way noone can see the unencrypted guest network. Is wires are not an option then you could buy two routers per sunch camara. At least one suporting WPA2 and wire that the the shielded open networks.

At this point though, ask yourself. How good are the camara's. I makes sense for some proper security camara (the multiple thousand euro kind). If it is a cheap camera then the obvious solution is the one you already mentioned.